# owl carousel fill the empty height of multiple images

Tags: html, css

I'm using owl carousel latest version and I have a little problem.
I have 3 images with different size.

My main div that is named "mydiv" must have must 614px width.

So, now, if you can see, looking at the images you can see there is a problem with the height (first has more width, second has more height and last one is a little small), there is too much space between the image and the bottom of the page.

How can I fix or How to fill the empty space?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {


    var owl = $('.mydiv').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        dots: true,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        mouseDrag: false,
    });
    


})
```

```css
body { background-color: green; }

.owl-prev, .owl-next {
  font-size: 65px !important;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  width: 614px !important;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.mydiv {
border: 2px solid red;
width: 614px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <body>
        <div class="mydiv owl-carousel">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5405231.jpg" alt="cristiano post" class="newsfeed-show-img-display">
                            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0b/3a/56/0b3a56ce1b5f0433f15a11115182b900.jpg" alt="cristiano post" class="newsfeed-show-img-display">
                            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/170x/cd/b2/07/cdb207efa5fb886defac79b7ac646f93.jpg" alt="cristiano post" class="newsfeed-show-img-display">
        </div>
        

        <!-- JQUERY -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- OWL CAROUSEL -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fill empty space by... What should be there is container has height X pixels and it's content has lower size?

Comment: what do you mean? @pavel

Comment: Your box has height 600px, first image has height 300px. What should be in the blank 300px under your first image? You can set flexible items height (arrow will be exactly underneath the image, will be move as img height is changed), you can set fixed img size (will be blured), or change your app to generate images in the resolution you exactly need.

Answer (score 0):

You can set owl-stage display as `flex` and then target images for 100% height.

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    display: flex;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {


    var owl = $('.mydiv').owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        dots: true,
        nav: true,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        mouseDrag: false,
    });
    


})
```

```css
body { background-color: green; }

.owl-prev, .owl-next {
  font-size: 65px !important;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  display: flex;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  width: 614px !important;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.mydiv {
border: 2px solid red;
width: 614px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css?">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <body>
        <div class="mydiv owl-carousel">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5405231.jpg" alt="cristiano post" class="newsfeed-show-img-display">
                            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/0b/3a/56/0b3a56ce1b5f0433f15a11115182b900.jpg" alt="cristiano post" class="newsfeed-show-img-display">
                            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/170x/cd/b2/07/cdb207efa5fb886defac79b7ac646f93.jpg" alt="cristiano post" class="newsfeed-show-img-display">
        </div>
        

        <!-- JQUERY -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <!-- OWL CAROUSEL -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really can't force higher image resolution this way. The result s blured.